# Trying to create a simple backup PowerShell script

Tags: powershell, backup

Trying to create a simple backup script, but every time I run the script below, I receive the following error:

```
Copy-Item : Cannot overwrite the item C:\Users\Jacob\desktop\file1.txt with 
itself.
At C:\Users\Jacob\desktop\test.ps1:5 char:1
+ Copy-Item $file $file.backup
+ ~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~
    + CategoryInfo          : WriteError: (C:\Users\Jacob\desktop\file1.txt:String) [Copy-Item], IOException
    + FullyQualifiedErrorId : CopyError,Microsoft.PowerShell.Commands.CopyItemCommand
```

Simple script:

```
Param(
    [Parameter(Mandatory=$true)]
    [string]$file
)

Copy-Item $file $file.backup
"$file has been backed up."
```

Comment: Great, but do you understand _why_ it worked?

Comment: Please do not edit an answer into the question. If you found a solution yourself it's perfectly acceptable to post it as an answer of your own.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`$file.backup` tries to expand the (non-existing) property `backup` on the string variable `$file`. This comes back with an empty result, so you're effectively running `Copy-Item $file` (without a destination), which causes the error you observed.

To avoid this issue you can do several things, for instance:

- define the destination as a string:

  ```
  Copy-Item $file "${file}.backup"
  ```
- append the extension by string concatenation:

  ```
  Copy-Item $file ($file + '.backup')
  ```
- use the format operator:

  ```
  Copy-Item $file ('{0}.backup' -f $file)
  ```